# How do I store the outputs of 1000 die rolls, 6 times into a matrix?

Tags: r, function, matrix, random

How do I repeat a function n times and bind the vector outputs into a matrix?

Or rather, how do I improve my function to get the intended result?

### So far I have:

```
sample(1:6, 1000, rep = TRUE)
```

### Have tried making into a function, but am stuck here.

```
droll_func = function(t){
    sample(1:6, 1000, rep = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Do you want: `matrix(sample(1:6, 6000, rep = TRUE), 6)` ?

Comment: Yes! I think this is it. Just to clarify, does this make a 1000 x 6 roll matrix? Or I guess I could just use the transpose function.

Comment: Just use `ncol` like: `matrix(sample(1:6, 6000, rep = TRUE), ncol=6)`

Comment: I think GKi's comment is superior to the checked answer.  Because a matrix is just a dimensioned vector.  As Gki notes, you can easily generate a random stream of ixj realizations as a vector and then create a matrix[i, j] with the stream as data.

Answer (score 2):

### Big thanks to GKi with the most efficient answer:

matrix(sample(1:6, 6000, rep = TRUE), ncol=6)

Answer (score 1):

```
droll_func <- function(n_times=1){
  output <- replicate(n_times, sample(1:6, 10, rep=TRUE))
  return(output)
}

test <- droll_function(2)
test
class(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that using `foreach` & `dplyr`.

```
droll_func = function(t){
  require(foreach)
  require(dplyr)
  # using foreach to iterate t times
  df <- bind_cols(foreach(i = 1:t) %do% {
      # for each i generate 1000 random from 1-6 and
      # create a df with one column name x_{{i}}
      tibble("x_{{i}}" := sample(1:6, 1000, rep = TRUE))
  })
  df
}
```

A trial

```
> droll_func(5)
# A tibble: 1,000 x 5
    x_1L  x_2L  x_3L  x_4L  x_5L
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     6     1     3     2
 2     6     5     6     2     3
 3     2     2     5     3     4
 4     1     6     3     6     5
 5     2     1     1     3     4
 6     4     5     4     5     6
 7     2     2     5     5     4
 8     6     1     6     3     5
 9     2     6     4     5     6
10     1     4     5     1     2
# … with 990 more rows
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you!